Как сохранить ответы пользователя в боте теллеграм через callback?
Я не могу разобраться как сделать так чтобы бот запоминал данные от пользователя которые вводяться через инлайн кнопки и будут выводиться после написания какой-то команды например:
какой ваш любимый цветок
(Инлайн кнопки: роза   ромашка)
пользователь нажимает
какой ваш любимый напиток?
(Инлайн кнопки: кола  спрайт  фанта)
пользователь пишет "результат"
и бот выдает то что выбрал пользователь
Раньше я делал все через прописку сценариев для каждого ответа но понимаю что так не может продолжатся

Записывайте в словарь.

Для хранения пользовательских данных диалога предусмотрены три уровня контекста диалога, пользователя, чата и бота. В этой статье все неплохо описано:
https://docs-python.ru/packages/biblioteka-python-telegram-bot-python/hranenie-dannyh/
